# PHP compare strings in loop with similar_text, but only show if match is unique

Tags: php, string, match, preg-match, matching

I have an array with movie titles. I want to match those movie titles with movies I have in a database. Furthermore, I do the comparison with PHP's similar_text() function. That works fine so far, but sometimes there are more than one 100% matches for one movie title. In that case, I want to exclude this comparison because I will do the match for that manually later. I only want to work with the matches, I can be sure it's the right one.

To show the matches with 100% and also over 80%, I use a switch / case. So to ignore the ones with multiple matches, I tried to find them with regular expression and then do an if-statement. But my approach is not working. It still shows multiple 100% matches.

Here is my approach so far:

```php
$movies = array( // full of movie titles );
foreach ( $movies as $movie ) {
            $sim = similar_text($movie->title, $db_title, $perc);
            switch($perc) {
                case $perc == '100 %':
                    $preg = preg_match('|^(?=[^%s].*?[%s][^%s]*$)[0-9a-zA-Z_-\s:;,\.\?!\(\)\p{L}(%s){1}]*$|u', $perc);
                    if ( $preg === 0) {
                        echo "$movie->title: $perc %\n";
                        break;
                    } else {
                        echo "no usable match!\n";
                        break;
                    }
                case $perc >= '80 %':
                    echo "$movie->title: $perc %\n";
                    break;
                case $perc <= '80 %':
                    break;
            }
            
        }
```

Google didn't really help me. You find numerous questions about similar_text itself, but not how to handle the case when multiple strings have a 100% match.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you so much!

Edit (clarification of the usecase): I have a large array with many movie names (and some other stuff related to the movies) in it. I also have a database with many movies in it. Because I don't have a unique identifier to make a match between the movies from the array and the ones in the db, I want to match the titles with similar_text. But sometimes a movie title exists 3 times with an exact 100% match. I want to find those cases, so I can handle those later and just work with unique 100% matches.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but if this part is true `if ( $preg === 0) {` then there is no match. Is that intended?

Comment: Okay, let me explain: I have a large array with many movie names (and some other stuff related to the movies) in it. I also have a database with many movies in it. Because I don't have a unique identifier to make a match between the movies from the array and the ones in the db, I want to match the titles with similar_text. But sometimes a movie title exists 3 times with an exact 100% match. I want to find those cases, so I can handle those later and just work with unique 100% matches.

Comment: So then you don't know up front which are the exact duplicate ones, and you will only know that after processing all the data right? Then you should keep track of the matches and the duplicates. The regex matches a pattern, which allows more than a unique string.

Comment: Okay I see, so I have to work on the regex? I am not very familiar with regex. Do you have an example or a good resource which helps me?

Comment: For example http://www.rexegg.com/ and https://www.regular-expressions.info/ and there are a lot of examples on SO. But in your code, you are getting a value for `$sim` which is not used. Then you switch on `$perc` which seems a variable not in the code example. Why do you need a regex?

Comment: $perc will be filled in the function similar_text. It saves the percentage of the matching between to strings. So $perc has values like 100 %, 88,567 % and so on. Thats how similar_text works. 

I just thought I need a regex. Maybe thats completely wrong and there is a more easy way. Thats why I asked that question here :D

Comment: Ah I see, the `$perc` parameter is by reference for [similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) I am not sure, but assuming the perc is 100, the strings are the same. Then store those 100% matches in an array. When done processing, you can get the duplicate values from the array.

Comment: I will try this, thank you very much!

Comment: If it wouldnt inside multiple loops, it would have worked with the array approach. But it takes to much memory for the amount of data. Still i have no solution how i can just use the matchings were no multiple matches happen...